# Deploying DAPP on cloud using docker

Tags: contract-deployment, docker, microsoft-azure, truffle-deployment

I am novice in docker technology. I have developed a basic private ethereum blockchain DAPP locally using Truffle and I want to deploy the same on cloud.

1) I need tutorials for how to crate a docker container for ethereum DAPP and how to deploy it on cloud (AWS or Azure).

2) I would also like to explore Azure ethereum blockchain as a service for making DAPP. Any tutorials for the same would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy your DAPP's smart contracts on a test etherium blockchain first and then afterwards you can deploy your DAPP on aws.

Docker Link : https://github.com/getamis/istanbul-tools
More about etherium testNets: https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-deploy-a-smart-contract-to-ethereum-testnet-e34fa5b10dd6

Comment: I don't want to deploy DAPP on public ethereum blockchain network I want to deploy it on private ethereum blockchain

Comment: For development you can use Ganache (http://truffleframework.com/ganache/) or for making private blockchains you can use Quorum (http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains)